# Spring boot async executor is creating more threads than core pool size and max pool size?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous

I am using spring boot async config to run certain functions asynchronosly .

Spring boot is creating more threads than corePoolSize and maxPoolSize
I have given both values same to define a fixed thread pool.

But spring creating and more number of threads.

See the below image taken from Jconsole
[image: Jconsole screenshot showing number of current threads running]

It is crating Async-57,Async-58,Async-59......

Is it just giving random numbers or creating 57th thread or 58th thread  (even having 30 fixed threads) ?

Please help me out as this is going to be in production which having limited POD resources.
This is my config . i am not using queue size because in production requests are ambigous.
i am using default size of queue which INTEGER.MAX

```
    @Value("${async.config.corepoolsize}")
    private String corePoolSize;
    
    @Value("${async.config.maxpoolsize}")
    private String maxPoolSize;
        
    @Bean("asyncExecutor")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(Integer.parseInt(corePoolSize));
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(maxPoolSize));
        executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(30);
        executor.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
```

Using more threads because these are used for only IO operations ( i kept this configuration values in app.properties file)

```
#Async configuration for IO operations
async.config.corepoolsize=30
async.config.maxpoolsize=30
```

Comment: did you `@EnableAsync` and `@Async` your function?

Comment: Thank you for comment @rickky13 yes async functionality is working that is not the issue. i think  spring is creating additional thread names or additional threads . that is the issue iam not able to understand.

Comment: I strongly suggest to actually inspect the threadpool. Going on this by the name of the threads is a bad idea (threads get destroyed and recreated because of the keep alive time). Also in your app there will be more threads and not only these 30 threads. So please inspect the thread pool and don't jump to conclusions based on names or wrong expectations (that your app would only use 30 threads in total).

Comment: thanks for comment deinum,. i inspect other threads only one async config is there with "Async- " prefix. and it is creating and destroying async threads also i checked it is approximately 30. but . i am not sure why new number is created for with "Async-". thats why i am confused. whether thread pool just creating threads with different names or it is creating more threads than 30 . just want to get confirmation  from an expert

Comment: @chittu Did u fix this issue ?. I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can test this configuration by setting core and max pool size to 2 and sending 20 events to process. Ideally thread name should be limited to 2 in such case.
try printing Thread.currentThread() value in logs as well.

Configuration is looking correct altough i have not used executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(30) and executor.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true) with my thread pool.